# How to add default values to XmlSerialized Lists without having duplicates?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I've run into this problem a few times and have solutions for it, but none that I like.  Consider having a class like:

```
public class MyData
{
     public List<string> Values = new List<string>();

}
```

Let's say that I always want Values to have at least one value,and this value should be "Default".  The constructor might be:

```
public MyData()
{
    Values.Add("Default");
}
```

That guarantees that new instances will always have at least the "Default" entry.  The problem is if I XmlSerialize a new instance, it will serialize with the "Default" value in Values.  That by itself is okay, but when when I deserialize it, the Default value gets added in my constructor, then once again through the deserialization, causing a duplicate value for "Default".

Like I mentioned above, I have done special things like making Load and Save methods that do the serialization internally and check for duplicates but that could be dangerous if someone serializes/deserializes the instance without passing through those methods.  Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?  Are there standard ways to solve it?